# Python Pydub Permission denied?

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7

When i run this code  :

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("i.mp3")
sound.export("F:\\bh", format="wav")
```

***A ffmpeg window pops up and i get this error:***[image: Error Pic]

Even if i run it with admin privilleges:
[image: Error with admin privilleges]

> Note :
>    The error occurs on every location that I try to export

Comment: same problem, no solution

Comment: Did you find the solution? @Anonymous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on Windows, face this problem, and also have issues installing `simpleaudio`, you can try installing `pyaudio` instead.

If you are using Anaconda, you can install `pyaudio` with

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```

For me, `simpleaudio` on Anaconda is only available for Linux and MacOS and not Windows.

Comment: `pip install pyaudio` worked for me on windows 11

Answer (score 5):

See this thread [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/209).  They suggest installing simpleaudio (`pip install simpleaudio`) to resolve this issue.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but fixed using the GillHawk solution from [this thread](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/209) (same link as Jondiepdoop gave). I added `f.close()` in the _play_with_ffplay function of the playback.py file :

```
def _play_with_ffplay(seg):
with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
    f.close() # close the file stream
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")
    subprocess.call([PLAYER, "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "-hide_banner", f.name])
```

Comment: amazing solution. In my case, I also need no the r' before the file path, like sound = AudioSegment.from_file('C:\\temp\\audio1.mp3', format="mp3").