# Why I can't use "play()" function in PyDub?

Tags: python, permissions, pydub

I just wrote simple code to play some music, using PyDub module in Python:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

audio1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("music.wav")
play(audio1)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\codes\Lessons.IzuchaemPython\pydub1.py", line 16, in <module> play(audio1)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 71, in play _play_with_ffplay(audio_segment)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 15, in _play_with_ffplay
seg.export(f.name, "wav")
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 867, in export
out_f, _ = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(out_f, 'wb+')
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4_bp0wu1.wav'
```

I have installed FFmpeg.
Please, explain to me how to make this simple program work.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/57634935/9977321

Answer (score 1):

You need to have either `pyaudio` installed or `ffplay`.

It will obviously open another window since it needs an application to play the audio, as an FYI. (Can't play from command prompt or terminal ;P)

Otherwise it should work, function is working fine for me.

Note: Also make sure you are in the right directories etc.,

Answer (score 1):

You can look this [Errno 13 Permission denied Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910583/errno-13-permission-denied-python)

or

I see the web from https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/

> Although pydub can open and save WAV files without any dependencies,
> you need to have an **audio playback package installed** to play audio.

Myabe you should try to install an audio playback.